# use_strict_mode in php sessions

Tags: php, session

Can anyone explain me what [use_strict_mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-strict-mode) in php.ini config is responsible for? In documentation it tells me the following:

> session.use_strict_mode specifies whether the module will use strict
>   session id mode. If this mode is enabled, the module does not accept
>   uninitialized session ID. If uninitialized session ID is sent from
>   browser, new session ID is sent to browser. Applications are protected
>   from session fixation via session adoption with strict mode. Defaults
>   to 0 (disabled).

My rudimentary understanding is that it creates always a session ID for you, but I already saw another [config option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) with does the same. So I assume that my understanding is wrong. So why do we need it? (The closest I saw is that it prevents OWASP A9, but it does not give me a lot of information).

Comment: OWASP A9? I wonder how you pick together those "knowns"

Comment: @hakre I did not get your comment. Can you please reword it?

Comment: OWASP A9 is nothing to prevent, it's a description of things done wrong. There is also no relation to session as far as I can say. So I just wonder, how do you manage to connect A9 to session.use_strict_mode (and also a bit as well how you connect that to session.auto_start).

Comment: Is there anything bad with a question? Or may be it does not fall into paradigm of `I am using magento/wordpress and can not configure a plugin?`

Comment: I didn't DV, but asking about "how can it be helpful" is often very broad and not clear what you aim with asking. Making that more clear can improve a question.

Comment: @hakre thanks. Got it, I removed that part. So right now I am asking only what is this option doing. Hope this is ok.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No that is not session auto start.

That is just, that if someone creates a session ID and send it to your server, and PHP realizes that there is no session so far with that ID (when strict mode is on) , PHP will create a new, different session ID an initializes the session to that new one instead to (as when strict mode is off) the user-injected value for session ID.

> A more elaboreated introduction and the motivation about *Strict Session ID Handling in PHP* has been outlined in an RFC in the PHP wiki: [Request for Comments: Strict Sessions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_sessions).

So with strict mode off, a user can decide which session ID she wants to use.

With strict mode on, the user can not decide that.

So you need it when you do not want to allow a user to pre-define the session ID value. You normally want to prevent that to reduce the attack surface.

Comment: just to make sure I got it right. I am in `strict_mode off` and no session was created. I send a request back to server and tamper with my cookie posting `PHPSESSID='hi'`, so the server initiates a session for me with `PHPSESSID` 'hi'. But if I do the same with `strict_mode` it will not happen. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is basically what the part you quoted already says in pretty much plain English …

Comment: This is also the reason why when something important happens (like the user logs-in or a session time-out period has passed) the session ID has to be changed by the webapp. Instead of strict-mode you can have a counter inside the session and also ensure that when the session is created the session ID has to immediately change.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Added another link that should explain it from a greater amount of POVs and angles.

Comment: Maybe you're using a different session_id try checking your session.use_strict_mode configuration.